# Powershell script not calling function

Tags: powershell

I have modified the following script and adapted it to our needs. All is working as expected but the call to the AppendLog in the TRY.

The log file gets created but it remains empty even after the script ran.

I have a thought that as the script is not removing any membership it wouldn't send an output to the log. But there are users that have DL's on them that can't be removed.

This is the code. Thank you!

```
function AppendLog ([string]$Message)
    {
        $CurrentAction = $Message
        $TraceLog += ((Get-Date).ToString() + "`t" + $Message + " `r`n")
    }



$path = "OU=Tango,OU=People,DC=Lab,DC=Dev";

Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $path -Properties memberof| Select DistinguishedName, @{n='memberOf';e={$_.memberOf -join '; '}} | export-csv 'd:/Remove AD Membership/usersbeforescript.csv' -NoTypeInformation

$ExceptGroup = "Domain Users";
$users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $path -Filter *

foreach ($user in $users) {
        try {
            $UserDN = $user.DistinguishedName
            Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter "(member=$UserDN)" | foreach-object {
                if ($_.name -ne $ExceptGroup) {
                    Remove-ADGroupMember -identity $_.name -Member $UserDN -confirm:$false
        }
            AppendLog “Removed from $user”
                }
         }catch {
                     AppendLog ”Failed to remove from $user”
                     }
    
    }


$datestring = get-date -format mmddyy
$logfile = ‘D:\Logs\Remove AD Membership\logfile_’ + $datestring + ‘.log’
$tracelog | out-file $logfile

Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $path -Properties memberof| Select DistinguishedName, @{n='memberOf';e={$_.memberOf -join '; '}} | export-csv 'D:\Remove AD Membership\usersafterscript.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: The lifetime of `$TraceLog` is tied to the lifetime of the function invocation, so you're not actually appending to anything - you just add a new message to a new local variable everytime, data that's then lost as soon as the function returns. Move the Out-File statement into the function so it actually flushes the data to disk

Comment: in addition to what MathiasR.Jessen pointed out, the `Out-File` cmdlet occasionally has some odd side effects. i would use the `Add-Content` cmdlet for adding to a file ... it can create a file, too. [*grin*]

Comment: Hi I added the $Tracelog into the function but now it only created two files (one line on each) and only for two users. Would you please give me an example or correct this code for me? I don't think I did it right.

```function AppendLog ([string]$Message)
    {
        $CurrentAction = $Message
        $TraceLog += ((Get-Date).ToString() + "`t" + $Message + " `r`n")
  $datestring = get-date -format mmddyy
  $logfile = ‘D:\Logs\AD Removal\logfile_’ + $datestring + ‘.log’
  $tracelog | out-file $logfile

    }```

Comment: In order to keep _appending_ to the target file, you must use `Out-File -Append` or `Add-Content`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comments and help! the issue is fixed now! :)